# Android - Comma as decimal separator on Numeric Keyboard

Tags: android, locale, android-softkeyboard, galaxy, decimal-point

We need to have a numeric keyboard for an `EditText`. The Keyboard should have decimal separator based on the device's selected locale. We implemented this by setting the custom `DigitsKeyListener` to the `EditText`

```
public class NumericDigitsKeyListener extends DigitsKeyListener {


    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {

        char[] acceptedCharacters = null;

            acceptedCharacters =  new char[] {
                    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                    new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefaultLocale()).getDecimalSeparator()

        return acceptedCharacters;
    }

    /**
     * @see android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener#getInputType()
     */
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;
    }
```

The above seems to work fine for most of the devices however for Samsung Galaxy S-II, the softkeyboard does not have comma in the keyboard.Th swype keyboard of the device displays the comma, but the default one does not.

I have tried overriding DigitsKeyListener as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498873)

Is there a way I can enforce all the devices to have comma (when applicable or even always) to be there on numeric keyboard?

Comment: My fix for this problem is here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63520135/11033601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63520135/11033601)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code has the same problem as using:

android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789,"

(except that your code is more generic)

The problem - as I understand, is that some keyboards just don't respect *digits* property when *inputType* is *numberDecimal*. This is a [documented bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2626) and the only way I found to avoid this behaviour is to use *inputType="text"* and set a input filter to restrict characters. Of course, the keyboard isn't proper for numbers but couldn't find a better solution. The filter would be something like this:

```
mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new DecimalInputFilter() });


public class DecimalInputFilter implements InputFilter {

    private static final String ALLOWED_CHARS = "0123456789,";

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
            final SpannableStringBuilder sourceAsSpannableBuilder = (SpannableStringBuilder)source;
            for (int i = end - 1; i >= start; i--) { 
                final char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
                 if (!StringUtils.contains(ALLOWED_CHARS, currentChar)) {    
                     sourceAsSpannableBuilder.delete(i, i+1);
                 }     
            }
            return source;
        } else {
            final StringBuilder filteredStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) { 
                final char currentChar = source.charAt(i);
                if (StringUtils.contains(ALLOWED_CHARS, currentChar)) {    
                    filteredStringBuilder.append(currentChar);
                }     
            }
            return filteredStringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```