# setKeyListener will override setInputType and change the keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, searchview, android-inputtype

Hi everyone I'm having a problem between two devices.

In practice using the `InputType` and the `KeyListener` I'm manipulating an `EditText` to make it receive the commas and numbers from the numeric pad (for more background check my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325496/searchview-use-multiple-comma-with-numeric-keyboard)).

Using the following code I'm able to do something like that:

```
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't work on some devices like `Asus ZenPad 8.0` or some Samsung.

Only the numeric pad is shown without the comma and therefore the user is unable to click and use it, an important note is that commenting the line of code below shows me correctly the pad with the comma available. But by doing this they are no longer able to use multiple commas in the same search.

```
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

**Without the KeyListener**

[image]

**With the KeyListener**

[image]

I've also read the android documentation about this and it says ([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener)):

> Interface for converting text key events into edit operations on an
>   Editable class. Note that for most cases this interface has been
>   superceded by general soft input methods as defined by InputMethod; it
>   should only be used for cases where an application has its own
>   on-screen keypad and also wants to process hard keyboard events to
>   match it.
>
> Key presses on soft input methods are not required to trigger the
>   methods in this listener, and are in fact discouraged to do so. The
>   default android keyboard will not trigger these for any key to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only deliver it
>   for some key presses to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or
>   earlier.

**So basically for old versions of android this doesn't work? How can I replicate the above behavior? (Basically how can I use the numeric keyboard with an unlimited number of comma)**

For any more details just comment i will gladly reply and add more info!

Thanks in advance,
Giacomo.

Comment: "I've also read the android documentation about this" -- what is "this"? It is not [`setKeyListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)). I cannot find your quoted section anywhere in the documentation. "So basically for old versions of android this doesn't work?" -- it's more that your hack is going to be unreliable. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of input method editors across the 26,000+ Android device models (and user-installed keyboards).

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, I added a link to the quoted documentation you can find the link under "(source)" ..also a big fan of yours, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't explain why that page does not show up when you search the docs on phrases like `targetting Ice Cream Sandwich`. Thanks for the link! Regardless, your approach makes assumptions. For example, there is no requirement for any IME to offer a comma on the keyboard when you request `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER + InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL)`. That is up to the developers of the IME. Saying nice things about me will not change that. :-) (though, thanks for the kind words!)

Comment: @CommonsWare Okey I understand that it is up to the developers of the IME to decide whether to show the comma by setting a certain type of InputType, though: Isn't InputType always determining which keyboard to show? Having said that why setting the KeyListener will change the keyboard? (I've added more info to the question, showing how is behaving.. also sorry if maybe I still don't understand or if I haven't explained myself well before).

Comment: "Isn't InputType always determining which keyboard to show?" -- it's a hint. What the developers of the IME do in response to the hint is up to the developers of the IME. IME developers probably think in terms of decimal and thousands separators, not strictly in terms of "comma". "Having said that why setting the KeyListener will change the keyboard?" -- it's possible that the manufacturer added special hooks for their own IMEs based on changes to `EditText` that react to the `KeyListener`. That's one aspect of what you are seeing that I would not have expected, to be honest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ah hint..That's nice I suppose :( .. If it is a suggestion, the only way would be to create my own keyboard inside my app?

Comment: You could do that, but you then may cause accessibility issues for users needing specialized keyboards.

Comment: Here is the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext

Comment: @JohnJeremias no is not..

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on what you are using the EditText for (would it be tragic if letters were also visible?) you could simply use default input type and simply set a filter on it so that it only accepts numbers and the one "character" (i.e. the comma) when you hit the keys. here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009533/android-comma-as-decimal-separator-on-numeric-keyboard) that lets you do that. admittedly it wont look as pretty but it will provide your users with a reliable experience that will work on all devices.

the alternative is to create your own keyboard as mentioned above

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, but yes.. it's tragic.

Comment: in that case i think the cleanest approach is to actually create your own keyboard. you can probably find some that have already been done by other people