# Soft keyboard with comma instead of dot for decimal separator in android

Tags: android

I have been reading some threads about this problem and some are not answered and others (from 2011) explain how this was a known bug.

Has this been solved? Is it possible right now to show soft keyboard with culture information? I would like to show a decimal keyboard showing a "," instead of a "dot" for the decimal separator.

Comment: My fix is here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63520135/11033601)

Comment: [See here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/DigitsKeyListener#getInstance(java.util.Locale,%20boolean,%20boolean) ) The DigitsKeyListener now accepts, locale which makes the softInput keyboard to accept ',' or '.' as decimal separator based on the locale.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the following workaround to also include comma as a valid input:-

**Through XML:**

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

**Programmatically:**

```
EditText input = new EditText(THE_CONTEXT);
input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
```

In this way Android system will show the numbers' keyboard and allow the input of comma. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you. Through Programmatically code is working.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to not show the '.' in the soft keyboard without creating your own one.
The solution than I found is:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789," />
```

This way when you press the '.' in the soft keyboard nothing happens; only numbers and comma are allowed

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by extending `NumberKeyListener` to accept ',' and '.', 
and overrode:

```
@Override
public int getInputType() {
   return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER 
          | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL 
          | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED;
}
```

Furthermore I set a TextWatcher on the EditText, which replaced all '.' with ',' in `afterTextChanged()`.

But I could not manage to show a comma on the softkeyboard.

Answer (score -4):

In android namespace you can use:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Which enables you to input the "."