# Impossible to append comma in Editable object

Tags: android, android-edittext

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an `EditText` with the following behaviour:

At first, the text show:

0.00 (en_GB local) or 0,00 (fr_FR local)

When user type the number 4, the Edittext show:

0.04 (en_GB) or 0,04 (fr_FR)

When user type another 6:

0.46 (en_GB) or 0,46 (fr_FR)

Etc.

Currently my code works very fine when the local is set to en_GB, however when the local change to fr_FR, I get an infinite loop.

Here is the code:

EditText layout:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/amount_ET"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="8" />
```

And the java code:

```
    amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_ET);
    amountEditText.setText(mValueToString());

    // ensure the cursor is always in the beginning of the text.
    amountEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (v.hasFocus()) {
                int len = amountEditText.getEditableText().toString().trim().length();
                if (len > 1) {
                    amountEditText.setSelection(0);
                    amountEditText.setCursorVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // add listener in order to intercept input on the EditText
    amountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // we only update if the value is not what we expect to avoid infinite loop
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty() && !s.toString().equals(mValueToString())) {
                // the cursor is always at the first position, so new char are in the beginning of the editable
                updateAmountTextView(s, s.charAt(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Update the new value with the given numeral and update the given Editable with the new value.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            if not null, will be updated with the formatted value.
 * @param c
 *            the char representing the number to insert.
 */
protected void updateAmountTextView(Editable s, char c) {
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(c - 48);
    mValue = mValue * 10 + i;

    if (s != null) {
        s.clear();
        s.append(mValueToString()); // when using fr_FR local, the coma is not appended leading to a false value in the editable.
    }
    amountEditText.setSelection(0);
}

/**
 * return the String formatted value.
 */
protected String mValueToString() {
    Double d = Double.valueOf(mValue) / 100;
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
    return formatter.format(d);
}
```

Has explained in the comments of the java code, the bug is in the method `updateAmountTextView()` where the `Editable` refuse to take the coma.
When changing the `inputType` of the `EditText` to the value `text` this bug doesn't occur, except I want to have a softkeyboard accepting numbers only.
I guess I should do something on the `Editable` object before appending value to it but I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: Did you switch the phone's language to change the locale? If not may be try the other constructor of `DecimalFormat` that uses a `DecimalFormatSymbols` parameter.

Comment: Yes the problem happen when I change the Local in the phone settings. However I don't think the problem comes from `DecimalFormat` as the formatted amount is already with a coma when the phone locale is set to fr_FR (which is what I want).

Comment: So `mValueToString()` returns the correct String (with comma)? My guess was that it has the wrong character and therefore gets rejected by the `EditText`. Seems I guessed wrong then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Comment: Thanks you very much your link solved my issue ! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: See here for some help on that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Comment: My answer (see above) was converted. Message: "trivial answer automatically converted to comment". So let's just leave it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the comments by https://stackoverflow.com/users/427291/devisnik adding the line `android:digits="0123456789.,"` in the `Edittext` layout solved the issue.