# Not able to use decimals with Numeric Keyboard (Xamarin Forms on Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've tried several solutions given on several forums and also asked on the Xamarin Forum, but all without a result: I want to create an Entry in Xamarin Forms where the user can add a decimal number. Problem is that my numeric keyboard disables the comma.

I was able to add a dot using a custom renderer, but since I live in The Netherlands I also need to have the option of using a comma. I test on a Samsung Galaxy S10 and it doesn't work there for no visible reason.

I created a demo for you take a look at, but since I cannot upload any files here you can find it on the thread I created on the Xamarin Forum ([demo file](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/06/occpl8zvh7qu.zip)). Maybe someone here can figure out what I need to do..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any other manufactorer and  Jarvan Zhangs answer will work. But the Samsung numeric keyboard always shows a dot, there's no way to change that. There are hundreds of people on the internet that want the same, not only for Xamarin but also for native android (e.g. [Samsung Galaxy Note II - Comma as Numeric Keyboard Decimal Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983521/samsung-galaxy-note-ii-comma-as-numeric-keyboard-decimal-separator)).
I ended up replacing every dot with a comma in the TextChanged event (in Xamarin.Forms code)...

```
Text = Text.Replace(".", ",")
```

If the Samsung numeric keyboard shows a minus above the dot, that's because it is signed. You can get rid of that with a custom renderer:

```
if (Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer.Equals("Samsung", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Control.InputType = InputTypes.ClassNumber | InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
        }
        else
        {
            Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance("1234567890,");
        }
```

The only other option is to install another keyboard, see linked SO question above...

Edit: while trying to find good examples of other failed attempts (lol) I found this acceppted answer:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175286/samsung-numeric-keyboard-makes-me-cry
I don't have a Samsung device in my homeoffice, so can't test, but maybe give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

To use the comma key in Xamarin.Forms for Android, try the following code.

```
public class EntryNumericKeyboardRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public EntryNumericKeyboardRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            this.Control.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance("1234567890,.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't work..I can enter the dot, but not a comma.

Comment: Did you test the code in another device? The issue may only occur for the samsung device, here is a similar issue case you could refer to:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/171091/android-numeric-keyboard-samsung-galaxy-no-decimals

Comment: @GaneshGebhard both solutions work fine. You just have to parse the input as [Culture Invariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-5.0), replace commas with dots and you are good to go.

Comment: This should be the correct answer for me.