# xamarin.forms decimal sperator different in different culture, CANNOT USE CULTURE INFO

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am simply parsing a double, say:

double x = 55.321;

When I now transmit this data to our server, the double becomes:
55.00000.

I have set my phone to italian.

Before I did that, the transmission was fine (in english).

However, BOTH langauges use a dot and NOT a comma. So both data should be fine, but appearently the italian dot is a different one from the english one (thats good to know...)

It all works when I set the culture:

```
    CultureInfo englishUSCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = englishUSCulture;
```

But when I do that, the app doesnt adjust its frontend language to whatever language is used on the phone, and only renderes english. So this is NOT an option.

How do I make sure, that always the same DOT is used without changing the culture info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transmitting data over an interface, it's often a good idea to use a defined constant normalized form for the data, e.g. always a decimal point and no thousands separator, etc. c# provides for this with the InvariantCulture.

Convert the number to a string on the front end

```
            double x = 55.321;
            string xstr = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Then transmit the string and convert it back to double on the receiving end using the invariant culture.

Comment: fantastic solution!

Answer (score 0):

I do that :

```
  if (answerValue != null)
    {
      decimal decimalValue;
      if (decimal.TryParse(value.Replace(",", "."), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out decimalValue))
      {
        answerValue.answerDecimal = decimalValue;
      }
      else
      {
        answerValue.answerDecimal = null;
      }
    }
```

Look at this answer too, [Not able to use decimals with Numeric Keyboard (Xamarin Forms on Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912009/not-able-to-use-decimals-with-numeric-keyboard-xamarin-forms-on-android), maybe can help you.