# dots and commas are not appearing in android numbers keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, special-characters, number-formatting, android-keypad

i implemented the keyboard number with , and . available for typing, in android EditText.

But when i install my application, in just some devices, the dots and commas are not prompting in the EditText after pressed, anyone have any ideas about that ??

And if is possible to be some keyboard configuration in the specific device ? any helps ? here is my code example...

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/notaosadd_quantidadenecessaria"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:digits="0123456789,."
            android:hint=""
            android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when i install my application, in just some devices, the dots and commas are not prompting in the EditText after pressed, anyone have any ideas about that ?

`android:inputType="number"` is just a suggestion, just as `android:digits` is just a suggestion. The input method editor can do whatever it wants. *Ideally*, the input method editor takes everything you request into account. But there are dozens, if not hundreds, of available input method editors, and none are required to honor your requests. Users can use whatever input method editors that they want, and so your app cannot assume that your `inputType` and `digits` will be honored.

> And if is possible to be some keyboard configuration in the specific device ?

You are welcome to examine fields on the `Build` class, like `PRODUCT`, and attempt to reconfigure your `EditText`. However, that would not be very effective. Users can use whatever input method editors that they want, including many that are available from distribution channels like the Play Store.