# Hold on backspace doesn't clear text one by one

Tags: android, android-edittext, backspace

I have an EditText implements TextWatcher but have a problem with Backspace key.
The first 5 characters are clear one by one when hold on backspace, but the last 5 characters that convert to image cannot clear one by one when hold on backspace.

Look the image :

[image]

1. MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Spannable.Factory spannableFactory;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory
           .getInstance();

   final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
           if (s.length() >= 5) {
               editText.setText(getTextToIcon(getApplicationContext(), s));
           }
           if(count!=0){                               // != key delete
               if (s.length() - 1 > start) {
                   editText.setSelection(start + 1);
               } else {
                   editText.setSelection(s.length());
               }
           }else{                                      // = key delete
               editText.setSelection(start);
           }

           editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
   });
   }


   public Spannable getTextToIcon(Context context, CharSequence text) {
   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(text);
   Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(stringBuilder);
   int index = text.length() - 1;
   for(int i = 5; i<=index; i++){
       spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, android.R.drawable.star_on),
               i, i + 1,
               Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   }
   return spannable;
   }
   }
   ```
2. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:maxLength="10"
       android:inputType="number" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Comment: As you are converting text to icon therefor you are not able to clear it on back space, so you need to check and convert it back from icon to text on back space to clear it.

Comment: @Vickyexpert : I can clear it by press on backspace one by one and clear text one by one, but when i hold on backspace the text doesn't clear one by one.

Comment: I think it's not because of convert it to icon, cause i use another method that i didn't convert it to icon, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Then I think you need to handle long press on backspace key, first do one thing hold on another key like "1" or "2" and check if it is working properly then check same for backspace

Comment: @ JohnWatsonDev : yest thank you. but `getTextToIcon` is at the bottom, you can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found a solution from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954719/5887320
Hope it will help other.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isEdiging;
        @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
        @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(isEdiging) return;
            isEdiging = true;

            String str = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
            double s1 = 0;
            try {
                s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
            ((DecimalFormat)nf2).applyPattern("###,###.###");
            s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

            isEdiging = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bro, the codes with bug is below:

```
if (s.length() >= 5) {
    editText.setText(getTextToIcon(getApplicationContext(), s));
}
```

You should change it to this:

```
if (count != 0 && s.length() >= 5) {
    // just set the text to the icon in input state instead of pressing delete key in soft method
    editText.setText(getTextToIcon(getApplicationContext(), s));
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Ok. wait i will test it.

Comment: It works. but not yet perfect. cause when you move cursor to the middle, the cursor will always go to the end.

Comment: Yep. You are right and I really understand your setSelection code now. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I tested the code you have editted. it work also. but when the first 5 character delete, the rest last 5 character not convert to number, it's still icon.

Comment: @HuoChhunleng You want the first 5 character always show as number?

Comment: My question ask above will work when the first 5 character delete and then the last 5 characters will be normal number not icon.

Comment: Yes i want the first 5 characters always show as number.

Comment: The soft method will lose focus when invoked the `setText()` method. This is the key point of this bug. Maybe you should implement your custom soft method.