# Keyboard dont show decimal separator in ladscape orientation

Tags: android, decimal, android-softkeyboard, landscape

When trying to work with a comma (`,`) as the decimal separator and `inputType="numberDecimal"` (or `"number"`), I have problem in smartphone in landscape mode, the comma is not showing.

My layout:

[image]

When I open the keyboard:

[image]

My EditText layout.

```xml
<EditText
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:digits="0123456789,"
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"
 android:text="5,2" />
```

And my default `Locale` is `pt_BR`, where the comma is the decimal separator.

In "tablets" is ok, because the keyboard is not full-screen.

[image]

If I remove `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`, also is ok, but does not show the numeric keyboard.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT #1**

A partial solution I found was to add `android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"`.

**EDIT #2**

The comma is [adopted by half the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system). Why is it so hard on Android? :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Comment: It is definitely not the answer.

Comment: The `inputType` settings aren't localized at all, so it's the same set of characters regardless of your locale. Have you tried this with a different keyboard app? The full-screen input mode is owned by the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, tried with [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) and [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), the two most used of the PlayStore. (Device Moto X 2 and Android 6.0)

Comment: I did not know the fullscreen mode was designed by the keyboard, the two that I have used are very much alike in the top half.

Comment: I tried too with [ASUS Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.ime) in Zenfone 5 and Android 4.4.2.

Comment: This problem exists with decimal '.' as well, when typing in a number field it isn't displayed on landscape mode.  It is actually entered it just isn't rendered in the edit control until you press done.

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="numberDecimal"` is for *decimal* inputs, it means all the digits from 0 to 9 including the decimal separator sign(.) can only be the input values. Comma is not the correct sign for the decimal separator. I think it may be a bug at your vendor not to produce all the correct localization values.
You can try to use

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789.,"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had tried. It is the same problem with `number` :( ... strange thing is that the problem only occurs when open the keyboard in full screen.

Comment: Specifying the digits doesn't make any difference.  I have localized my edit control to use comma or decimal, neither are rendered.