# I can't type commas in an numeric entry in cross platform in Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I am working on a project which is in Xamarin Cross Platform  in Android.
I am not to able to get Input of Commas from numeric keyboard.
here is the code:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=CalculationItem.HourlyRate}" Keyboard="Keyboard.Numeric" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

But In Android Studio I acheived by doing this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/germenCurrency"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="0123456789,"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

In xamarin i am not able to get input of Commas

Thanks in Advance.

Regards, Vivek Patel

Comment: What is the comma supposed to be? The decimal-separator? Have you tried "."?

Comment: yes this is "." working .But i also want input of this ","

Comment: Not too familiar with UI design on Android but I guess you must set the Locale or something in that direction. "germenCurrency" -> I guess you want German Number format which has "," as decimal separator.

Comment: Is the keyboard set to German?

Comment: This seems rather old but maybe still relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext

Comment: @Fildor may i know how to set keyboard for GermanCurrency

Comment: As I said: I am not familiar with GUI design in Xamarin/Android. Neither setting the Keyboard. That was just a shot into the blue. The keyboard layout should adapt to the inputType setting, but I don't know how to change the Locale. In the Link - see above - it sais there may be a Android bug. But it is from 2010 so I don't know if this is still relevant.

Comment: thank you so much for your response