# Kotlin EditText - Use comma or point based on region

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an EditText with point separator as default. I want to use point if region is United States and comma if region is Europe (not only one for one region)

Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal separator comma (',') with numberDecimal inputType in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext)

Comment: I want to use comma if Europe and point if US, not only comma.