# Replace key in Samsung keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to replace a key from a Samsung keyboard to use a custom text. My client requires that the decimal separator should be a comma instead of a dot. The problem is that Samsung only enables the dot key instead the comma.

I used `android:digits="0123456789,."` to enabled both, and if the user taps the dot then in the EditText it will be replaced by a comma.

Here is what is looks currently:

[image: current]

Here is what I want:

[image: solution]

As you can see, another app was able to change the label for the key. The red key is a dot whose text is ',' and the green key is the original comma that is disabled.

In other keyboards like Gboard and SwiftKey, both keys are enabled using `android:digits` and both will input a comma after replacing the dot.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decimal separator comma (',') with numberDecimal inputType in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821539/decimal-separator-comma-with-numberdecimal-inputtype-in-edittext)

Comment: @AjithGopi no, the answers are mostly to replace the characters in the EditText, I want to replace the label of the keyboard. The handling of the replacing characters is already done.

Comment: @allnex what is the name of the app? Maybe it is possible to reverse engineer their approach.